# Django Admin /admin two times one server different port

Tags: django, django-admin, nginx-config

currently I facing an issue to create two django projects parallel working on one server system.

Konfiguration:

- nginx ubuntu server such as 1.1.1.1
- django project 1 such as 1.1.1.1/admin with Port 8000
- django project 2 such as 1.1.1.1/demo/admin2 with Port 9000

Currently if I start both (django project 1 and 2) manage.py runserver successful and if I change path("admin/", django.contrib.admin.sites.urls) to path("admin2/", django.cotntrib.admin.site.urls) this gives me the Not Found Error.

Is there any way to use two django projects parallel on one server in a different GitHUb folder structure and the same IP ?

Comment: please add some info how you run the project "behind" nginx. Gunicorn? Apache? Virtual hosts?

Comment: with virtual hosts and for example with this nginx settings there both django projects are locate in different folders on the webserver...

Comment: upstream testdata {
  server unix:///.../app.sock;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test....de;
  location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///.../app.sock;
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host; //Port 8000
  }
  location /demo/ {
    proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1:9000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}